# Insert into same table with different code_store

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two stores, store 1 and 2, store 1 is closed and a need to insert all his clients into the same table but with code_store being 2 now. The structure of the table is

```
Code_clients_store (PK)  code_clients  code_store
--------------------------------------------------
     1                   35               1
```

I need to do something like this:

```
      2                   35               2
```

Insert the same client with code_store different, but don't delete the old client with store 1.

I'm trying something like this

```
Insert into table t_clients_stores 
from t_clients stores 
where cod_store = 1 
set cod_store = 2
```

But it's not working, someone know a better way to do this?

Comment: What are the column names of your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Insert into t_clients_stores (cod_store, code_clients)
select 2, s.code_clients
from t_clients stores s 
where s.cod_store = 1 

and not exists ( select 1 
                 from t_clients t 
                 where t.cod_store = 2 
                 and and t.code_clients = s.code_clients )
```

[INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

Comment: This way,it will insert all clients from store 1 into into same table with cod_store 2?

Comment: Shouldn't your columns come after the table? `insert into t_clients_stores (code_store, code_clients)` ?

Comment: @ViniciusNascimento Yes that is what you asked for

Answer (score 1):

You want `insert` . . . `select`:

```
Insert into t_clients_stores(code_clients, code_store)
    select code_clients, 2
    from t_clients stores 
    where cod_store = 1 ;
```

Comment: You also need to think about clients (`code_clients`) which are already in store (`code_store`) 2.